# Transform dict into 2 key dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like the below:

```
{'AL': {'FL': 1, 'GA': 0, 'MS': 0, 'TN': 0},
'AR': {'LA': 0, 'MO': 0, 'MS': 0, 'OK': 0, 'TN': 16, 'TX': 0}
...}
```

I'd like transform it to a two key-pair dictionary.

`FlowDict[('AL','FL')]`
returns `{('AL','FL'): 1)}`

I saw this on another [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303993/elegant-way-to-transform-a-list-of-dict-into-a-dict-of-dicts) and tried to implement it as follows:
`{i.pop('AL'): i for i in FlowDict}`. But I don't think this is the direction I need to go. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nested dictionary comprehension comes in handy here:

```
>>> FlowDict = {(key1,key2):value for key1 in d for key2,value in d[key1].items()}
>>> FlowDict
{('AL', 'FL'): 1,
 ('AL', 'GA'): 0,
 ('AL', 'MS'): 0,
 ('AL', 'TN'): 0,
 ('AR', 'LA'): 0,
 ('AR', 'MO'): 0,
 ('AR', 'MS'): 0,
 ('AR', 'OK'): 0,
 ('AR', 'TN'): 16,
 ('AR', 'TX'): 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your question won't quite work. That will just merge dicts.

A nested dictionary comprehension, however, will work for you:

```
test = {'AL': {'FL': 1, 'GA': 0, 'MS': 0, 'TN': 0},
'AR': {'LA': 0, 'MO': 0, 'MS': 0, 'OK': 0, 'TN': 16, 'TX': 0}}

flattened = {(main_key, sub_key): value for main_key, sub_dict in test.items() for sub_key, value in sub_dict.items()}
print(flattened)
```